# Using R, is it possible to dyn.load() a shared object library (.so) file directly from a URL?

Tags: r

I'm trying to figure out if it's possible to use the R dyn.load() function to load a shared object library (.so) file directly from a URL, instead of first having to download it into your R working directory.

The R environment that I'm working with runs on an AWS lambda server, and as a consequence I can only read, not write to or create, files in the working directory.

Any help would be much appreciated!

(.so file URL: http://cloud.sowiso.nl/images/uploads/mvtnorm.so)

Comment: You could try `dyn.load(url("http//:yoururl.com"))` ?

Comment: Thank you for the response. I've tried this, but that returns the following error: 'character argument expected'.

Comment: Just an idea, but I think lambdas allow you to create your own custom runtime. Perhaps you could build one already with the shared object (and avoid having to download it)?

Comment: Hmm that just might do the trick, I'll definitely look into that. Thx!